# How do i set Rails Credentials for multiple Production Environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple production server environments `production`, `staging`, `sandbox`, and `dev` hosted on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

I want to be able to set different credentials for each of these production environments.

Currently, when i do `rails credentials:edit --environment production`, all the secrets i put in that file will be accessible by all four environments since they are production environments.

How can i differentiate between them?

Comment: you cna check this thread : https://nts.strzibny.name/creating-staging-environments-in-rails/ ( it was written for the old secret file but can adapt easily to credentials) although why you want to have different environment variables for staging ? Usually staging is made to test production code to limted users base. Then to me it should share same environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Create more environments. Rails justs ships with three environments preconfigured as thats the bare minimum and works well enough until you need a staging environment or CI or ...

An environment is basically just a string that you pass via `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` or via the command line flags. If you for example run `rails s -e foo` it will:

- Load `/config/environments/foo.rb`
- Use the `foo:` segment in `database.yml` to connect to your DB.
- Use the credentials in `config/credentials/foo.yml.enc` and that key in Rails 6+.
- `Rails.env.foo?` will be true.